# byacc %defines syntax error when compiling with make command

Tags: cygwin, bison, yacc

I am trying to run [Ymer](https://github.com/hlsyounes/ymer) tool in windows 10 platform. I have installed g++, gcc, yacc via cygwin. After configure command, When I am running make command to compile the application, it generates following error.

```
PS C:\ymer> make
/bin/sh ./ylwrap src/grammar.yy y.tab.c src/grammar.cc y.tab.h echo src/grammar.cc | sed -e s/cc$/hh/ -e s/cpp$/hpp/ -e s/cxx$/hxx/ -e s/c++$/h++/ -e s/c$/h/ y.output src/grammar.output -- byacc -d
    byacc: e - line 514 of "/cygdrive/c/ymer/src/grammar.yy", syntax error
    %defines
    ^
    Makefile:2467: recipe for target 'src/grammar.cc' failed
    make: *** [src/grammar.cc] Error 1
```

It seems the [grammar.yy](https://github.com/hlsyounes/ymer/blob/master/src/grammar.yy) file causes the problem. Anyone knows how to solve this problem. BTW I am not familiar neither with yacc nor make files. I am just very new to cygwin as well.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

The `%defines` declaration is bison-specific (not part of [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html) yacc).  The file [grammar.yy](https://github.com/hlsyounes/ymer/blob/master/src/grammar.yy) contains some bison features which [byacc](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/manpage/yacc.html#h2-EXTENSIONS) implements, but this is not one of those.  (From the [description](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Decl-Summary) in the manual page, it seems that this is equivalent to the standard command-line option `-d`, making it less than useful).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I tired 'bison -y' instead of byacc, and it worked.

Comment: Feel free to 'accept' the answer (it appears to have resolved the problem).